# (python) using a csv file to store details of a map

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, navigation

i am creating a text based game in python. in this, i will be using a CSV file to store the different tiles on the map. i would like to know what code i would need to essentially request the 'co-ordinates' of the map tile.

for example, if i was to create a tile with the co-ordinates x = 5, y = 6; it would store the information (GRASS1S2s1w, for example) in the 5th column and the sixth row.

i would also like to know how to call the specific cell in which the data is stored.

any alternate ways of doing this (not CSV) will be ignored. this is for a school project and i am too far through to change from CSV (i would have to change a lot of words in my plan.)

note: GRASS1S2I3Sc means 'grass tile' (GRASS), "stone" (1S), "scrap" (2S) and "wood" (1W)

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2d list containing all the information. That way you can access a value of a specific coordinate like

`list[x][y]`

Then save the list with `csv.writer`

You can read the existing csv file as a list similarly to access the info.

Comment: apologies, but could you give a coded example of the whole thing, i.e opening file, creating file and so on? i haven't used csv for years...